# Angular SpringBoot Multipart File upload

Tags: angular, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am trying to create a page where users can post images along with their details. Now as am testing the spring boot services from postman i am successfully able to get the files in the service. As am trying to do the same from angular5, the multipart file is not getting recognized in service and am always getting empty array.

```
 @RequestMapping(value= "/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public AppResponse<User> saveUser(@RequestParam("userId") Long userId, @RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> files, HttpServletRequest request){
    int i=0;
    User user=userLogic.getUserById(userId);
    String[] imageUrls= new String[files.size()];
    try {
        for(MultipartFile file:files) {
            if(file.getContentType().equals("image/jpeg") || file.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("image/pjpeg")) {
                ObjectMetadata meta= new ObjectMetadata();
                meta.setContentType(file.getContentType());
                meta.setContentDisposition(userId+"_"+i);
                PutObjectResult result=s3Client.putObject(PHOTO_DIRECTORY,getFileName(userId, i),file.getInputStream(),meta);
                imageUrls[i]=PHOTO_DIRECTORY+"/"+getFileName(userId, i);
            } else {
                throw new InvalidFileFormatException("This filetype is not accepted");
            }

        }
        user.setActorPhotos(imageUrls);
        userLogic.saveUser(user);
        return new AppResponse<>(false, "Success");
    }
    catch(InvalidFileFormatException | IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception in file upload");
        return new AppResponse<>(true, "Failure");
    }
```

And my angular service code is as follows

```
 postPhotos(files: any,userId:any): Observable<any> {
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("files",files,"files");   
  return this.http.post<Result>(URLConfig.postPhotos+"?userId="+userId, formData);
```

}

I have tried adding headers like multipart/form-data from angular and also set it to undefined. Either way i am getting error. I have searched stackoverflow extensively before posting here and tried all those solutions without any help.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set  set content type as multipart/form-data in headers. 
Modify your service method like below and give a try.

```js
 postPhotos(files: any,userId:any): Observable<any> { 
  const url = "whatever /the/ url is ";
  let headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
             });
        let options = { headers: headers };
     return this.http.post<Result>(url, formData,options);  
 }
```

Note that , additionally you need to set response type (i.e accept) in headers too. 
Let us know if it works.

Comment: I was able to get rid of it without adding headers. But all i had to do was add the each file in form data as seperate item using for loop rather than directly adding the array of files in form data.

Answer (score 0):

```
postPhotos(files: any[], userId: any): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'});

    let formData = new FormData();

    files.forEach((item: any) => {
        formData.append("files", item, "files");
    });

    
    return this.http.post<Result>(url, formData, options);
}
```